# Creating a list of dictionaries using a for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to get the following code:

```
dirpath = os.getcwd()
path = f"{dirpath}/static/user_images/user_{user_id}"
l = []
ratings_list = []
for filename in Path(path).glob('**/*.*'):
    file = os.path.basename(filename)
    query = text('SELECT * FROM ratings WHERE photo_name = "{}" AND photo_user_id = {}'.format(file, user_id))
    resultproxy = db.session.execute(query)

    for row in resultproxy:
        l.append(row.rating)
        total_ratings_count = len(l)
        average = statistics.mean(l)
        lowest = min(l)
        highest = max(l)

        data = {
        file: average, 
        "min": lowest,
        "max": highest,
        "number_of_ratings": total_ratings_count
        }
        ratings_list.append(data)
```

to output a list of dictionaries that have each have the image name, and max,min,avg ratings;
something like:

```
[
{"image_name": avg_rating, "max": max_rating, "min": min_rating, "number_of_ratings": ratings_count},
{"image_name_2": avg_rating, "max": max_rating, "min": min_rating, "number_of_ratings": ratings_count},
{"image_name_3": avg_rating, "max": max_rating, "min": min_rating, "number_of_ratings": ratings_count},
]
```

instead what I'm getting is the individual values repeated for each image (i.e., if there are 4 ratings recorded then there will be 4 entries returned with their individual ratings rather than their averages)

when I move the data items outside of the second for loop as follows:

```
for filename in Path(path).glob('**/*.*'):
    file = os.path.basename(filename)
    query = text('SELECT * FROM ratings WHERE photo_name = "{}" AND photo_user_id = {}'.format(file, user_id))
    resultproxy = db.session.execute(query)

    for row in resultproxy:
        l.append(row.rating)
    total_ratings_count = len(l)
    average = statistics.mean(l)
    lowest = min(l)
    highest = max(l)

    data = {
    file: average,
    "min": lowest,
    "max": highest,
    "number_of_ratings": total_ratings_count
    }
    ratings_list.append(data)
```

I get the error `statistics.StatisticsError: mean requires at least one data point`. When I `print(l)` it returns an empty list.

Comment: It would help if you could show what your current output looks like

Comment: You need to provide a [mre]

Comment: Can you add the output of `resultproxy`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I've found the easiest way this can be done is to have sql do the math work, which seems to take the complication out of it. The working code is:

```
    @classmethod
    def load_user_ratings(cls, user_id) -> dict:
        dirpath = os.getcwd()
        path = f"{dirpath}/static/user_images/user_{user_id}"
        d = {}
        ratings_list = []
        for filename in Path(path).glob('**/*.*'):
            file = os.path.basename(filename)
            sql = text('SELECT AVG(rating) as average, MAX(rating) as maximum, MIN(rating) as minimum FROM ratings '
                       'WHERE photo_name = "{}" AND photo_user_id = {}'.format(file, user_id))
            resultproxy = db.session.execute(sql)

            for row in resultproxy:
                for column, value in row.items():
                    # build up the dictionary
                    d = {**d, **{column: value}}
                    d.update({"image": file})
            ratings_list.append(d)
    return ratings_list
```

For clarity, `resultproxy` is a sqlalchemy object that outputs something like `<sqlalchemy.engine.result.ResultProxy object at 0x10fdbfad0>`

The real issue in this problem was getting the results to be put into the dictionary properly after the math work was done with it. Moving the `ratings_list.append(d)` to outside the second for-loop accomplishes that as long as the AVG/MIN/MAX is being handled by the sql query. Otherwise, you will get a `statistics.StatisticsError: mean requires at least one data point` error, which when printed in the terminal shows that the initial list is empty and then iteratively gets populated.

I suppose that makes sense, but I was unable to figure out how to have python handle the numbers properly. This is a bandaid fix IMO as I suspect at some point I'll need to do more complex mathematics which is outside the capability of SQL.